# Using Wordpress, create a custom post type that has another post type within it

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to create a custom post type in Wordpress for a course section on a site. I want to be able to add a course and then within that course add lessons. I know how to create basic custom posts but haven't been able to figure out a post within a post. Is this even possible?

The url structure would look something like this:

www.mysite.com/courses/awesome-course/lesson-1/

This is the sort of thing I'm looking for but want to build it myself: http://www.woothemes.com/products/sensei/

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Use a custom taxonomy for the courses: http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Answer (score 0):

Install the Custom post types plugin by iLocalize http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/. They have a lot of tutorials on how to add the custom posts to a page. This tutorial http://youtu.be/1SXyHbgjYaI here is the best I've found but there are more the wp-types website.